# Read stream "freezes" despite data available after a certain amount of messages

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# application that communicates with the clangd language server.
clangd is started as a separate process managed by my C# program and communication works via I/O redirection.

My program is exchanging [language server protocol request-response pairs](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/overview) with clangd. Requests are sent to clangd via its process' StandardInput stream and responses are read using its process' StandardOutput stream. clangd emits debug information using its process' StandardError stream.
I am using async methods for reading and writing in order to keep the user interface responsive.

However, after sending the third [textDocument/didOpen](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_didOpen) message, my program freezes while trying to read the response.
Making use of the StandardError stream I found out, that clangd processes the third `textDocument/didOpen` message correctly, as it emits debug messages, meaning the response should be available on StandardOutput.

I saved the requests in a file and sent those to a clangd instance running on the command line, which worked like a charm. [I attached that file in case you need it.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At5ExrckDtBighA-Em0Lin4hgxIx)

Furthermore, the debug messages which read at the bottom of the `SendRequest` method indicate that the file was opened:

```
I[09:55:53.552] <-- textDocument/didOpen(26)
I[09:55:56.512] Updating file C:\Temp\crossrail\src\ClLogic.cpp with command [C:\Temp\crossrail\src] clang C:\Temp\crossrail\src\ClLogic.cpp -resource-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\8.0.0
```

Below you can see the LSP client code for reading and writing the responses. I marked the location that gets blocked.

```
private Process languageServer;
private StreamWriter requestWriter;
private StreamReader responseReader;
private StreamReader errorReader;
// ...

public void Connect(String workingDirectory)
{
    if (this.Connected == false)
    {
        this.currentMessageID = LSP_FIRST_MESSAGE_ID;
        this.languageServer.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        this.languageServer.Start();
        this.Connected = true;

        this.requestWriter = this.languageServer.StandardInput;
        this.responseReader = this.languageServer.StandardOutput;
        this.errorReader = this.languageServer.StandardError;
    }
}

public async Task<String> Query<T>(JsonRpcRequest<T> request)
{
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await this.SendRequest(request);
        return await this.ReadResponse();
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.Release();
    }
}

private async Task SendRequest<T>(JsonRpcRequest<T> request)
{
    request.ID = this.currentMessageID;
    ++this.currentMessageID;

    String requestBody = request.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(requestBody);
    await this.requestWriter.WriteAsync(requestBody.ToCharArray(), 0, requestBody.Length);
    await this.requestWriter.FlushAsync();

    if (request.ID == 26) // ID of the third textDocument/didOpen message
    {
        //await this.ReadErrors(); // the debug messages following the third textDocument/didOpen request are printed correctly
    }
}

private async Task<String> ReadResponse()
{
    String contentLengthHeader = await this.responseReader.ReadLineAsync(); // blocks after the third textDocument/didOpen message
    int responseLength = Int32.Parse
    (
        contentLengthHeader.Substring(contentLengthHeader.IndexOf(LSP_HEADER_KEY_VALUE_DELIMITER) + LSP_HEADER_VALUE_OFFSET)
            .Trim()
    );
    await this.responseReader.ReadLineAsync();

    char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    int totalReadBytes = 0;
    while (totalReadBytes < responseLength)
    {
        int readBytes = await this.responseReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.Append(buffer, 0, readBytes);

        totalReadBytes += readBytes;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    return response.ToString();
}

public async Task SendFileCloseMessage(DocumentCloseRequest request)
{
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await this.SendRequest(request);
        this.responseReader.DiscardBufferedData();
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.Release();
    }
}
```

Here is my code using the LSP client's methods for sending the textDocument/didOpen message:

```
private async Task InitializeLanguageServer(bool highlightFunctionDeclarations)
{
    if (this.languageServer.Connected == false)
    {
        this.languageServer.Connect(this.workingDirectory);
        await this.SendInitializationMessage();
    }
    await this.SendOpenFileMessage();
    await this.LoadSymbolDeclarationLocations(highlightFunctionDeclarations);
    await this.LoadSymbolUsages();
}

private async Task SendInitializationMessage()
{
    InitializationRequest request = new InitializationRequest
    (
        this.workingDirectory,
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id,
        false,
        ApplicationSettings.LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROTOCOL_SUPPORTED_SYMBOLS
    );
    Console.WriteLine(await this.languageServer.Query(request));
}

private async Task SendOpenFileMessage()
{
    DocumentOpenRequest request = new DocumentOpenRequest(this.filePath, "cpp", 1, this.SourceCode);
    Console.WriteLine(await this.languageServer.Query(request));
}
```

InitializeLanguageServer is called in the constructor **without** `await`, but that shouldn't be a problem, as clangd is fast enough to process every source code file in a maximum of 2.5 seconds.
The `languageServer` member is retrieved using TinyIoC:

```
public SourceViewerVM()
{
    // ...
    this.languageServer = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<LanguageServerProtocolClient>();
    #pragma warning disable CS4014
    this.InitializeLanguageServer(highlightFunctionDeclarations);
    #pragma warning restore CS4014
}
```

**Edit:**

The reading really blocks and isn't just waiting for a new line character. If I put the follwing code at my breakpoint which usually reads the StandardError, execution is blocked too:

```
if (request.ID == 26) // 26 is the ID of the third textRequest/didOpen message
{
    char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int readBytes = await this.responseReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); // blocking
    Console.WriteLine(new String(buffer, 0, readBytes));
    //await this.ReadErrors();
}
```

Comment: What is `responseReader` ? You left out the critical part ...

Comment: Thank you, I added them at the begin of my source code.

Comment: Are you 100% sure, it's _not_ waiting for a "newline"?

Comment: Yeah, see my latest edit